# OAuth-2.0 bottleneck in Authorization Code Grant authorization protocol

Tags: language-agnostic, oauth, oauth-2.0

Consider OAuth-2.0 Authorization Code Grant protocol.

As described in standard draft http://tools.ietf.org/html/ietf-oauth-v2-26 on `Figure 3 : Authorization Code Flow` a `Client` is getting token on behalf of `Authorization Code` received from `User-Agent`. Suppose that `User-Agent` is intentionally sending wrong codes to the `Client`. If `Authorization Server` makes some protection against `brute force` way of obtaining `Access Token` by banning `Client` for some reasonable amount of time (by IP or by `Redirection URI` host name). If in our case the `Client` is supposed to process horde of requests from multiple different `User-Agent's` the `Client` will stop to serve all its users altogether if there's only one malicious one exists.

So the `Client` becomes a bottleneck in a situation described above.

==== EDITED ====
Any ideas how to evade the bottleneck problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking:
"how to evade this problem and NOT to expose **Authorization Code** to User-Agent?"

This is not possible.  The OAuth request flows through the user's browser so you can't prevent exposing the authorization code to the user.

If you're a victim to an attack like this, I'd suggest putting the same protection into your Client that the OAuth provider is putting into their Authorization Server.  Namely, stop allowing new authorization codes to be sent from a User-Agent that's abusing your service.  If they send more than, say, 3 invalid tokens per hour, ban them for an hour or two (by IP address).  Of course, this could lead to you denying access to your site from proxy servers because of one bad user on the proxy, but that's life.

Comment: It IS about the `Access Token` but our situation is quite cumbersome for us because there's one only Auth type implemented by Auth provider which we are obliged to use. I will delete phrase about `Auth Token` because it's misleading and offsetting point of my question. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I think the response remains the same though-- the only way to prevent this attack on your client is to implement the same type of protection as the OAuth provider has implemented to prevent your client from being used in these brute force attacks.

Comment: If you're just using OAuth for *authorization* and the user is already authenticated (via username/password for instance), you could require that authentication be checked before you make a call to the OAuth provider.  You could then limit the # of OAuth requests per authenticated user, and use CAPTCHAs or similar to make it harder to create users.  Basically, you can make it much harder for machines to use your service-- but probably not make it impossible.  At some point, the attackers may decide there are easier targets and leave you alone though :)